# Termux closes after loading llama LLM

Tags: termux

The same happens with alpaca.cpp.
The model loads and then termux closes.Sometimes it doesn't close, but instead gives final message : " : killed", where it shows some number. I'm not sure it might be PID.

I've created additional swap file. I'm trying to run this on Samsung Note 8 with 6GB ram.I have swap file 4.5GB.

I don't know what i'm missing, on google I see that other ppl, run the same models succesfully just by build-ing the git-project and then run it successfully.

I run Android 12 Lineage OS 19

Do you have suggestion?

Comment: Do you use the outdated Termux version from Google Play Store or the version from F-Droid?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. For those who are not familiar with it, could you [edit] and add some more details about "Llama LLM" and "alpaca.cpp"? What and how did you try to run it?

Comment: I use the F-droid version. I used "make" to build git projects. When i start the script, it loads the model and then termux closes...Or sometimes a messege appers with some number and it says "killed",.

Comment: Just making sure you've disabled Android 12's phantom process killer: https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/2366 (Not sure if LineageOS changes the default state).

Comment: Phantom process killer is disabled